# How to setup Tomcat 7 Postgresql datasource for Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, tomcat7, war

For some reasons I've to fine-tune the jdbc connecton, and I've found, the context.xml is the way I can do that. ( http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#PostgreSQL )

So, I create context.xml:

```
<Context>
<Resource
    name="jdbc/connectorDs"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
    url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/somedb"
    username="pguser"
    password="pgpw"
    maxActive="20"
    maxIdle="10"
    maxWait="-1" />
</Context>
```

Add some config to web.xml:

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>postgreSQL Datasource example</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/connectorDs</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

And modify the hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
<property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:jdbc/connectorDs</property>

<!-- THE ORIGINAL CONFIG -->
<!-- <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost/somedb</property> -->
<!-- <property name="connection.username">pguser</property> -->
<!-- <property name="connection.password">pgpw</property> -->
```

But this kind of konfig doesn't work: `SEVERE: Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not find datasource`. I suppose the dataource not exist or the datasource connection string `java:jdbc/connectorDs` is not proper. Anybody has any experience with it? How to set my connection propertly, or how to set additional properties on connection?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:comp/env/jdbc/OracleDS</property>
```

I don't think you need to declare datasource in both web.xml and server.xml. Try to remove the web.xml one if it still don't run

Comment: Works fine without `web.xml` config code. Thanks both of you.

Answer (score 2):

In hibernate.cfg.xml, try replacing

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:jdbc/connectorDs</property>
```

with

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:/comp/env/jdbc/connectorDs</property>
```